# Solving alternate infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Suppose we have an alternating series of the form $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{f(n)}}{n^2} \text{ where }
 f(n) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{n is prime} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$.

How would one go about proving that this series converges or not? Does this series have a closed form solution?

Comment: It converges absolutely, so there is no problem with convergence.  I doubt there is a convenient form for the sum, however.

Comment: Can you see that $\left|\dfrac{(-1)^{f(n)}}{n^2}\right|\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: Yes this seems true and because of this equation the function converges absolutely and so has a finite limit less then $\frac{1}{n^2}$ Thank you for the response.

Comment: Just a little thing: pay attention to the domain of your terms. You can't evaluate $\frac{(-1)^m}{n^2}$ in $n=0$, and I don't know how you would define $f(n)$ for $n=0,1$, so I suggest to start from $n=2$.

Comment: I added the question to reflect this observation

Comment: If you do the sum from $n=1$ you get about $0.740439$. So if you do the sum from $n=2$ you get $1$ less, about $-0.259561$.