# How to use a conditional statement in an infinite series to approach a specific limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, notation

If I were to sum the infinite series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}...\frac{1}{2^\infty}$$

but as soon as the previous partial sum 
$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ becomes greater than 0.9 I subtract $\frac{1}{2^n}$ instead of adding it, forcing the series to approach 0.9.

What would would be the simplest form to write that, possibly using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)? I'm not sure how to deal with the negative value though.

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}.[\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} < 0.9]$$

or is this valid?

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(n)=\begin {cases} \frac{1}{2^n} & \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} < 0.9\\
\frac{-1}{2^n} & \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} > 0.9 \end {cases}$$

or maybe:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(n)=\begin {cases} \frac{1}{2^n} & \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^n} < 0.9\\
\frac{-1}{2^n} & \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^n} > 0.9 \end {cases}$$

Comment: Did you think about a recursive definition? $f(1) = \frac1{2^1}.$ For $n > 1$: $f(n) = +\frac1{2^n}$ if $f(1) + \cdots + f(n-1) \leq 0.9$ and $f(n) = -\frac1{2^n}$ if $f(1) + \cdots + f(n-1) > 0.9$.

Comment: That is kind of what I was hoping for. I just need to express it as elegantly as possible because it's part of a much larger expression which I would like to keep as succinct as possible.

Comment: Stackoverflow suggested this related question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663358/solving-alternate-infinite-series

which I think is quite nifty. Unless there are better suggestions I will probably go with something like that.

Comment: Using Iverson brackets, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, where $$f(n)=2^{-n}-2^{-n+1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k) \ge0.9\right].$$ This even works with $n=1$, as long as you suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{0}f(k)$ is the empty sum with value $0$.

Comment: Very neat Mike! If you would like to move this to the answer I’ll accept this as the answer.

Comment: To my surprise it seems that for $n>1$ the identity
$$\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\geq0.9\right]=\left[n\equiv1,2\pmod{4}\right],$$
holds. Or is this just a coincidence for small $n$?

Comment: The identity in my previous comment holds, though only for $n>2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Iverson brackets, this can be written as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is defined by
$$
f(n)=2^{-n}-2^{-n+1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k) \ge0.9\right].
$$
When $n=1$, we use the convention $\sum_{k=1}^0f(k)=0$, as this is the empty sum.

Unlike most function definitions (let $f(n)=n^2$), this one is inductive, so it takes a little thought to convince yourself that it is a valid definition. Since the value of $f(n)$ only depends on the value of $f(k)$ for $k<n$, with the base case $f(1)=1$, there is no problem.

Comment: It is interesting to note that $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$ which could be read as "ignore first term and flip the sign of the second term" which in turn could be used to reduce the infinite series to a closed form (I think). I'll persue that some more. I like that fact that 0.9 can be replaced by a variable here and that this expression could be applied to any value of that variable, which I wanted to know, although I neglected to mention that.

Comment: @dataphile That reduced form is just the binary expansion of $0.9$, of course. This makes the $n$th partial sum $$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)=\frac{2\lfloor 2^{n-1}\cdot 0.9\rfloor+1}{2^n}$$(By stubtracting consecutive partialsums, you can also regain a nice expression for $f(n)$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you hit the nail on the head. I've written a sine function that calculates $\sin(\theta)$ by adding up the binary expansion of the angle towards $\theta$ and then using that to add up the opposing edges of those angles towards $\sin(\theta)$.

Here is the javascript implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/dataphile/9j76oxma/11

I am trying to write the above implementation in math notation.

Comment: @dataphile: while that notation *is* correct, I would *not* recommend using it in almost any mathematical setting. The norm in math is to use natural language for these complicated constructions.

Comment: Point taken @CarlMummert. The reason I am pursuing a math equation is because I need it in a function of which I need to calculate the inverse.

Answer (score 3):

**Claim:**

The sign of the $k$-th term is precisely $(-1)^{\lfloor\tfrac{k+1}{2}\rfloor}$, excep for $k=1$ and $k=2$. To be precise, setting
$$f(1):=\frac12,
\qquad 
f(2):=\frac14,
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
f(k):=\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\tfrac{k+1}{2}\rfloor}}{2^k}
\quad
\text{ for all }k>2,$$
yields the desired sum. This means that for all $m\geq1$ the partial sum $S_m:=\sum_{k=1}^mf(k)$ satisfies
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
S_m<0.9\quad&\implies&\quad f(m+1)>0,\\
S_m>0.9\quad&\implies&\quad f(m+1)<0.\tag{1}
\end{array}$$

**Proof:**

This is clear for $m=1$ and $m=2$. To simplify $(1)$ note that $S_m\neq0.9$ for all $m$ because the denominator of $S_m$ is a power of $2$ whereas $0.9=\frac{3}{10}$. So $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$S_m<0.9\qquad\iff\qquad f(m+1)>0.$$
Moreover, the sign of $f(m+1)$ can be expressed simply in terms of $m$ because
$$f(m+1)>0
\quad\iff\quad
(-1)^{\lfloor\tfrac{m+2}{2}\rfloor}>0
\quad\iff\quad
m+2\equiv2,3\pmod{4}.$$
For $m>2$, to get rid of the first two irregular terms in the partial sum $S_m$, set $T_m:=\sum_{k=3}^mf(k)$. Then $T_m=S_m-\tfrac34$ and $(1)$ now simplifies to
$$T_m>\frac{3}{20}\qquad\iff\qquad m\equiv0,1\pmod{4}.$$
Writing out the first few summands of $T_m$ shows that if $m$ is even we can group the summands into pairs to get a simple geometric sum, for which it is easy to find a closed form:
\begin{eqnarray*}
T_{2n}&=&\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}\right)
-\left(\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{64}\right)
+\left(\frac{1}{128}+\frac{1}{256}\right)
-\cdots\\
&=&\sum_{k=2}^n\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k\left(2+1\right)
=3\sum_{k=2}^n\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k\\
&=&3\frac{\left(-\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2-\left(-\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(-\tfrac14\right)}
=\frac{3}{20}\left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
&=&\frac{3}{20}-\frac{3}{20}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
In particular, this last expression shows that $T_{2n}>\frac{3}{20}$ if $n$ is even and $T_{2n}<\frac{3}{20}$ if $n$ is odd. This proves $(1)$ for all even $m$. For odd $m$, we simply add one summand to $(2)$ to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
T_{2n+1}&=&
\frac{3}{20}+\frac35\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}\\
&=&\frac{3}{20}+(-1)^n\frac35\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n-\frac12\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n\\
&=&\frac{3}{20}+\left((-1)^n\frac35-\frac12\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n,
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that $T_{2n+1}>\tfrac{3}{20}$ if $n$ is even and $T_{2n+1}<\tfrac{3}{20}$ if $n$ is odd. This proves $(1)$ for all odd $m$, and hence for all $m$.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Your input is much appreciated! I think that your expression is equivalent to what I wrote; note that I start the series at $k=1$.

Comment: Also, it is quite late here, if you have more suggested edits I will look at them tomorrow. I also hope to finish the proof for the odd partial sums; I don't think it's difficult, it's just too cumbersome for me at the moment.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley You are right, I have corrected the double/split use of $m$. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: My goodness, this is fantastic @Servaes! Please share the proof for odd m when you have a chance. I would love to see it. Thanks

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I have had some sleep and coffee and cleaned up the proof.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Thanks for the very thorough check, it was clearly needed! I have changed the first sum on the second line of (2), starting it at the index $k=2$ in stead of $k=1$. I believe all the errors you have listed have now been corrected.

Comment: @dataphile I have included a proof for odd $m$.

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks @Servaes!

Comment: +1 It's a very pleasant surprise, the way this series works out.